# populating double array logic error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, functional-programming

Implementing some paging algorithms in java script for practice. 
I get the proper output on the arrays I want to push into the multidimensional array(double) but it only pushes the final version. Im printing to the console and this is what im getting it should be populated with all the different versions of the frames. Is this a weird JS thing with arrays or what?
    //variable declaration
    var frameNumber=3;
    var refStringSize=6;

```
var faultCount=0;
var refString = [];
var _frames=[];
var arrayOfDisplayArrays=[];

console.log("refString: "+refString);
//didnt include other functions 
//"driver"
 for(i=refStringSize;i>0;i--){
    var x = refString.shift();
    //if frames are not filled
    if(_frames.length!=frameNumber){
        if(!_includes(_frames,x)){
            _frames.push({'x':x,'checked':false});
            faultCount++;
            console.log('----')
            console.log(_frames);
            arrayOfDisplayArrays.push(_frames); 

        }   

    //if frames are filled
    }else{
        if(!_includes(_frames,x)){
        var index=getLRUIndex(_frames,refD);
        _frames[index]={'x':x,'checked':false};
        faultCount++;
        console.log('----')
        console.log(_frames);
        arrayOfDisplayArrays.push(_frames); 

        }
    }
    refD.push(x);


 }
 console.log(arrayOfDisplayArrays);
```

and this is my output(ignore checked):

```
    refString: 2,9,4,5,8,9
    ----
    [ { x: 2, checked: false } ]
    ----
    [ { x: 2, checked: false }, { x: 9, checked: false } ]
    ----
    [ { x: 2, checked: false },
      { x: 9, checked: false },
      { x: 4, checked: false } ]
    ----
    [ { x: 5, checked: false },
      { x: 9, checked: false },
      { x: 4, checked: false } ]
    ----
    [ { x: 5, checked: false },
      { x: 8, checked: false },
      { x: 4, checked: false } ]
    ----
    [ { x: 5, checked: false },
      { x: 8, checked: false },
      { x: 9, checked: false } ]
    ---------array of arrays----
    [ [ { x: 5, checked: false },
        { x: 8, checked: false },
        { x: 9, checked: false } ],
      [ { x: 5, checked: false },
        { x: 8, checked: false },
        { x: 9, checked: false } ],
      [ { x: 5, checked: false },
        { x: 8, checked: false },
        { x: 9, checked: false } ],
      [ { x: 5, checked: false },
        { x: 8, checked: false },
        { x: 9, checked: false } ],
      [ { x: 5, checked: false },
        { x: 8, checked: false },
        { x: 9, checked: false } ],
      [ { x: 5, checked: false },
        { x: 8, checked: false },
        { x: 9, checked: false } ] ]
```